# The addEventListener is returning an error when I use it on the name object

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods, addeventlistener

```
<input type="text" id="name" />

<script>
    var name = document.getElementById("name");

    name.addEventListener("focus",select,false);

    function select() {
      console.log("Focused!");
    }
</script>
```

I created a variable called name in the global scope and selected the nameId element. Then I called addEventListener on the object but it returned as undefined method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with the ID "name", so btn evaluates to undefined. Undefined has no method addEventListener

You will need to use document.getElementById('btn')

it appears **name** is reserved in javascript, I know name is a keyword in a lot of other languages. Change your code to this and it works

```
var nme = document.getElementById("nameId");
var email = document.getElementById("emailId");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

if(window.addEventListener) {
    nme.addEventListener("focus",select,false);//This is where I get the error
    nme.addEventListener("blur",deselect,false);
    email.addEventListener("focus",select,false);
    email.addEventListener("blur",deselect,false);
    submit.addEventListener("press",validate,false);
} else {
    nme.attachEvent("onfocus",select);
    nme.attachEvent("onblur",deselect);
    email.attachEvent("onfocus",select);
    email.attachEvent("onblur",deselect);
    submit.attachEvent("onpress",validate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define btn...

btn = document.getElementById("btn"); vs document.getElementById("name");